# jsdom does not parse javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jsdom

To explain the title a bit further, it seems like jsdom does not seem to be parsing the external/internal javascript. Either that, or I'm completely missing something here.

The following snippet is suppose to visit hulu and print out the `search-container` div, which I believe is added to the site dynamically through javascript. The code does not seem to work.

I don't understand why it isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

Snippet:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var request = require('request');

var url = "http://www.hulu.com";


// Catch any errors.
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log('Caught exception: ' + err);
});

// Request page from server.
request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error)  return;

  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("Loaded webpage, parsing");
    jdom(body); // Parse page into jsdom
  }
})

function jdom(body) {

    var doc   = jsdom.jsdom(body, null, {
        features: {
            FetchExternalResources   : ['script'],
            ProcessExternalResources : ['script'],
            MutationEvents           : '2.0',
        }
    });

    var window = doc.createWindow();
    jsdom.jQueryify(window, "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js", function(window)     {

        //var $ = window.$;
        var $ = window.jQuery;
        var document = window.document;

        console.log(window.$().jquery); // print jquery version


        $(document).ready(function() {
            //console.log( $('#search-container').html() );

            setInterval(function() { // waitForElement()

                console.log( $('#search-container').html() );

            }, 2000);

        });

    });

}
```

Result is `null` every 2 seconds.

It should be noted that there is an exception caught a few seconds after the above code is ran.

Exception:
`Caught exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentView' of undefined`

Comment: This is a rather complex page. I wouldn't expect that jsdom can emulate all behaviour of a modern web browser (maybe I'm wrong). Would PhantomJS be an option for you? What exactly do want to achieve? BTW is it necessary to load external jQuery (v1.5) when there is jQuery (1.7.2) already on the page?

Comment: I do believe I tried PhantomJS but modifying the page contents, using jQuery, etc all seemed troublesome due to having to call page.render and then using the result. I've looked at several of the alternatives (for headless browsers or even full webkit browsers) but there were always at least a few drawbacks. IE: zombie was my favorite but came across the same problems, due to it using jsdom. My goal is to be able to build an API that focuses on media websites, can crawl and navigate. That is my ultimate goal.